# prove compact and inf sup

Tags: real-analysis

I try to wrote down some summary of myself from compact set section

> when k is the nonempty compact subset of R
>
> any sub set of K should be finite subset of K
>
> so open cover{T} of K there should be the finite subcollection of
>   T1,,,,,Tn
>
> and since open cover {T} is the finite open set.
>
> there should be exist of supT and infT.

1. ( is finite open cover definition is enough to say there is supT and infT???)
2. what is the conceptually difference between bounded and sup,inf
3. what is so important about compact set?
4. what is the relation between compact set, inf,sup, bounded(especially) ,open set
   (every thing is in R) 
   if its open finite set can you say its bounded?

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space $(X,d)$, for example $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual metric, compactness of a subset $S$ is equivalent to the set being closed and bounded.

If a set in $\Bbb{R}$ is bounded, then by definition it's bounded above and below and so has an $\inf$ and $\sup$.  Prove this.

Comment: Your first assertion is incorrect. In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, compactness of a set is indeed equivalent to the set being closed and bounded. For general metric space this is false: only one way implication is true.